# redux-toolkit fetch many data in createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux-toolkit, unhandled-promise-rejection

I need function in redux-toolkit to fetch all data from others slices.

I have this code:

```
export const getAllData = createAsyncThunk(
  'fetchRoot/getAllData',
  async (_, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    const promises = [dispatch(getUsers()), dispatch(getSettings()), dispatch(getClients())];

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((res: any) => {
        // for (const promise of res) {
        //  console.log('SSS', promise);
        //  if (promise.meta.rejectedWithValue) {
        //    return rejectWithValue(promise.payload);
        //  }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
);
```

My question: if one of slice fetch function (example: getUsers()) is rejected, how to reject promise.all?

getUsers() function and extraReducers:

```
export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk('users/getUsers', async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const res = await agent.Users.getAll();
    return await res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return rejectWithValue(err);
  }
});
```

```
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      // GetUsers lifecycle ===================================
      .addCase(getUsers.pending, (state) => {
        state.apiState.loading = true;
        state.apiState.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.apiState.loading = false;
        state.data = payload;
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.apiState.loading = false;
        state.apiState.error = payload;
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it basically right.  Once the `Promise.all(promises)` has resolved you will have an array containing the resolved value of each of your individual thunks.

The individual promises [will always resolve](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions) and will never reject.  They will resolve to either a `fulfilled` action or a `rejected` action.  In some cases, it will make sense to use the `unwrap()` property which causes rejected actions to throw  errors.  But looking at the `.meta` property [will work too](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#checking-if-a-promise-rejection-was-from-an-error-or-cancellation).

You can check your action with the `isRejected` or `isRejectedWithValue` functions which serve as type guards, that way you won't have any TypeScript errors when accessing properties like `action.meta.rejectedWithValue`.

The hard part here is trying to `return rejectWithValue()` from inside a loop.  I would recommend unwrapping to throw an error instead.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, unwrapResult } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const getAllData = createAsyncThunk(
  "fetchRoot/getAllData",
  async (_, { dispatch }) => {
    const promises = [dispatch(getUsers()), dispatch(getSettings()), dispatch(getClients())];

    const actions = await Promise.all(promises);
    return actions.map(unwrapResult);
  }
);
```

Note that there is no reason to `try`/`catch` in your `getUsers` thunk if you are going to `rejectWithValue` with the entire caught error object.  Just let the error be thrown.

```
export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk('users/getUsers', async () => {
  const res = await agent.Users.getAll();
  return res.data;
});
```